# Rails 5.1: Autoload path is not working even when file present in autoload path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

we have a folder called `lib` in the project folder root and also this in the application.rb

```
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

but I get a error `uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::ShopifyApi`

when I run in the rails console, this works

```
load Rails.root.join('lib/shopify_api.rb')
ShopifyApi::SCOPES
```

but not in the application.

Any help on how to fix this would be really great.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `::ShopifyApi::SCOPES`?

Comment: yes, that did not work

Comment: Try this also to mutate array `config.autoload_paths << "#{root}/lib"`

Comment: If you want to autoload code don't put it in lib. It defeats the whole point.